# Capture desktop without my window

Tags: windows, desktop, capture

I want to create a recording of desktop content, but without a certain window. The role of this window is to provide a text that will be read, while recording desktop changes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out camstudio: http://camstudio.org/

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a two-monitor environment and moving the reading window to the other desktop?

There are even USB powered digital picture frames, quite cheap, some of which can serve as second monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You could first capture the desktop window (wallpaper, icons, start menu, etc). Then iterate through each visible window, and capture each window's display (skipping over the window that you don't want to show). For each window, just copy its captured bitmap onto the background (placed at the proper coordinates).